# solve : $\frac{\cos(x)(\sqrt{3}\sin(x)+\cos(x)+2)}{2\cos(x)+1}\leq1\quad x\in[0,2\pi]$

Tags: inequality

Solve
$$\frac{\cos(x)(\sqrt{3}\sin(x)+\cos(x)+2)}{2\cos(x)+1}\leq1\quad x\in[0,2\pi]$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please try to format your question better or at least make it clear enough so that someone else can format it for you.

Comment: Also, please share where exactly you are stuck, after attempting it yourself?

Comment: A few links to help you lean some basics about writing math on MSE: [here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

First, solve the equality
$$
\frac{\cos (x) \left(\sqrt{3} \sin (x)+\cos (x)+2\right)}
{2 \cos (x)+1} = 1
$$
which leads to the equation
$$
\cos (x) \left(\sqrt{3} \sin (x)+\cos (x)+2\right) = 2 \cos (x)+1
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\sin (x) \left(\sqrt{3} \cos (x)-\sin (x)\right) = 0.
$$

---

More details can be posted if needed. You will find the roots are, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align} 
  x_{1} &= k \pi \\
  x_{2} &= \frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi
\end{align}
$$

[image: plot]